# Magento 1.9.3.8 : how to remove download link in New purchase order mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-email

I want to remove download link from purchase order mail.

Anyone know about that?

[image]

Comment: what type of order you placed and get mail? also attach screenshot here?

Comment: Downloadable product order. In Item description  with download link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this file:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/email/order/items/order/downloadable.phtml

**Remove below code from that file.**

```
<?php if ($links = $this->getLinks()->getPurchasedItems()): ?>
            <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <dt><strong><em><?php echo $this->getLinksTitle() ?></em></strong></dt>
                <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
                    <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($link->getLinkTitle()); ?>&nbsp;
                        (<a href="<?php echo $this->getPurchasedLinkUrl($link) ?>"
                            style="color:#1E7EC8;"><?php echo Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('download') ?></a>)
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Welcome bro, happy to help!